# How do I define an Ubuntu Linux16.04 systemd service for fastcgi-mono-server4 or xsp4?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, mono

How do I define an Ubuntu Linux16.04 systemd service for fastcgi-mono-server4 or xsp4?

I have already defined an Ubuntu Linux16.04 systemd service for apache2 by copying obex.service to apache2.service and changing the ExecStart line in apache2.service.

When I do the same thing for xsp4.service where xsp4 is a C# executable , systemctl status xsp4.service complains about: Failed to execute operation: Too many levels of symbolic links. Is it because in /etc/systemd/system ,  I "soft" linked xsp4.service using the command ln -s /usr/lib/systemd/user/xsp4.service xsp4.service?

Also, we would like to configure the ordering of service files so that apache2.service runs before xsp4.service.

Here is xsp4.service :

```
[Unit]
Description=Xsp4 service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xsp4 --port 9000 --root /var/www/firstaspnet

[Install]
Alias=dbus-org.bluez.obex.service
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Too many symbolic links normally only happen if you have a recurrent symbolic link.  I bet that it is chocking on the `Alias` parameter since you are using the same `Alias=` for the apache service you mentioned.  You really do not need the `[Install]` section and/or the `Alias=` parameter to either `apache` or `mono`, kill that section in both unit files.

Comment: @grochmal, I totally agree with you about  "Too many symbolic links". What happens if I put Restart=always underneath ExecStart in the [Service] section? Where do I find the trace files to debug systemd? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, i'm having difficulties to understand your comment.  It is sometimes tricky to communicate using text only.  If you could edit the question with results of what you tried after reading my comment it will be clearer i believe.  Anyhow, one thing i understand and can say that: to get `systemd` log all you need to do it `systemd -l status <service_name.service>`

Comment: @grochmal, When I run systemd status xsp4.service I get: Excess Arguments for the following xsp4.service: [Unit]
Description=xsp4

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xsp4 --root /var/www/firstaspnet --port 9000
Restart=always


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target  May I ask what I did wrong? Thank you.

Comment: To solve this issue we need at least: the content of `/usr/lib/systemd/user/xsp4.service` and the reason you are not using it diretly; the content of the default apache service unit on your systemd (systemctl cat apache2.service ?) and why you are not using it directly. You shoud also remove the `[Install]` section from your xsp4 service unit.